# PayU Integration Web Service URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, payu

I am trying to Add Web Service Reference of PayU Web Service Url (given in PayU Integration document) through the Visual Studio solution.
But unable to retrieve any services.

Test Server

Web Service URL
https://test.payu.in/merchant/postservice

You can refer the following link
http://www.scribd.com/doc/77209934/PayU-Technical-Integration-Document-v1-3

I am unable to understand where the problem is ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the provided URL is actually a WebService?

Seems that it might be a page where to perform a POST.

I quickly googled that and I found [this page](https://secure.safeshop.co.za/documentation/Code/CodingExample_CSharp.htm).

Hope that helps.

Comment: provided url is given in the document as shared on the above link.

Comment: I was not saying that the URL was wrong, I was just wondering if it was a web service behind https://test.payu.in/merchant/postservice or a page to post to. And concerning the PayU Technical Integration document URL you shared, it's only a preview of the first page and you cannot see the whole document without paying to create a Scribd account (that's the reason why I goolgled to gather more information in order to help you).

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to old version of docs. Check the latest docs in the following URL based on integration:
https://devguide.payu.in/merchant-integration/introduction/

Comment: The question is 10 years old, so that's not a surprise that URLs are old too. It's better to make a comment instead of an answer, which in reality is not an answer.